# Get array of rows depends on value in different columns

Tags: google-sheets

How can I get this array of rows? Can I do this without google script?

[image: Look a picture]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fuiBJrY6O1cPjR70U8meB14pe5cc6cvK6jJj8A_9tn4/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1):

yes:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 IF(B3:Q10="";;A3:A10&"♀"&B3:Q10&"♀"&B2:Q2)); "♀"); 
 "where Col2 is not null"; 0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you clarify what is symbol "♀"?

Comment: @AntonWhite its just a unique symbol acting like a separator for SPLIT function. you can use any symbol you wish ♀♫♂♪♥♦♣♠☼►